# Typescript: Web worker cannot create an object from an imported class

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, web-worker

I'm attempting to create a new object from a class, in a Web worker. (The worker code is in Worker.ts, which generates worker.bundle.js. Wrapper.ts runs on the main thread and creates the worker, using worker.bundle.js.)

I am importing the class into my Web worker and, when the message event fires, I check to see if the message data has a specific property. If it does, I create a new object from my class.

But, when I run the code, I never hit the `debugger` breakpoint. If I comment out the object creation, I will hit the `debugger` breakpoint anytime the evaluated condition is true.

Trying to troubleshoot, I added error handling in a separate `addEventListener` call, with nothing but a `debugger` statement. That breakpoint is *never* hit, regardless of whether I comment or un-comment the object creation.

Nothing I've read anywhere says (or even suggests) that you can't use a class to create an object in a Web worker. yet, my worker fails silently every time I try to do so. Is there something special about class usage in a web worker, which causes different behavior than when you are working in the main browser thread?

Thanks!

##### Worker.ts

```js
import { MyTempClass } from '../../LibraryB/MyTempClass';

addEventListener('message', function (e) {
  if(typeof e.data.id !== 'undefined') {
    const {id, payload} = e.data;
    debugger;
    // The ^^^ debugger will not be hit, if I uncomment the next line...
    //let test = new MyTempClass('https://somesite.org');
    const err = null;
    const msg = {
      id,
      err,
      payload: 'result'
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    this.postMessage(msg);
  }
});

addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  debugger;
  // ^^^ this breakpoint is never reached. So, apparently, there aren't any errors being thrown.
});
```

##### Wrapper.ts

```js
interface IWorkerMessage {
  id: number;
  payload: any;
}
const resolves = {};
const rejects = {};
let globalMsgId = 0;
// Activate the worker, returning a promise
const sendMsg = (payload: any, worker: Worker): Promise<any> => {
  const msgId = globalMsgId++;
  const msg: IWorkerMessage = {
    id: msgId,
    payload
  };
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // save callbacks for later
    resolves[msgId] = resolve;
    rejects[msgId] = reject;
    worker.postMessage(msg);
  });
};
// Handle incoming result
const handleMsg = (msg: MessageEvent): void => {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(msg.data, 'payload')) {
    const { id, err, payload } = msg.data;
    //debugger;
    if (payload) {
      const resolve = resolves[id];
      if (resolve) {
        resolve(payload);
      }
    } else {
      // error condition
      const reject = rejects[id];
      if (reject) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          reject('Got nothing');
        }
      }
    }

    // purge used callbacks
    delete resolves[id];
    delete rejects[id];
  }
};
// Wrapper class
class Wrapper {
  worker: Worker;
  constructor() {
    this.worker = new Worker('./Worker.bundle.js');
    this.worker.onmessage = handleMsg;
  }

  call = (payload: any) => {
    return sendMsg(payload, this.worker);
  };
}
export default Wrapper;
```

Comment: Try installing an error handler on the worker object in the wrapper as well

Comment: Did you check the compiled *Worker.bundle.js*? As soon as you start using the `MyTempClass`, the imported module actually gets required and the bundle needs to contain the class and its dependencies. Does this work correctly?

Comment: Added error handler in the wrapper as well. It's not being fired. However, per your 2nd comment, you're right: the class I am importing in the worker is NOT actually being added to worker.bundle.js. Got any thoughts as to why?

Comment: i don't know how you're bundling your modules, so no thoughts. You might want to ask a new question about that, with more details about the build setup